# How to show date fetched from the database(saved as date) to the <input type=date> in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, html, data-binding

## DOB:

## datatype in dbms is 'date'

## i want to fetch that date and want to show it to this type of input box

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a SqlDataReader, you can do:

`DateTime datetime = reader.GetDateTime(columnNum);`

This will automatically convert to DateTime. If you just want the text, use the above method and:

`string formattedDate = datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");`

Comment: Error 2 No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 arguments

Comment: OK, I found the problem and it was with what I told you. It's Monday, please forgive me. Check the edited code and it should work

Comment: Then you should have to just change your formatting to `"yyyy-MM-dd"` and it should work. I don't have experience with the `date` type text box, and my work machine only has IE, so I can't test for you.

Comment: hmmm... thanks man!!! I will try... and if you can ask someone please help me out....